# Python incrementally add 1 to regular expression search and join line in Python

Tags: python, regex, join, count, increment

By just adding the n=1, n+=1. the code was adding the numbers to the next line of file.  So I added the line.replace and line.join to the code, but now it is pulling the next line of code up.  Please note that there are multiple lines in the file between lines that contain border.

```
Desired Output to file
border1
border2
border3

Current Output
border1{
border2{
border3{
```

My code now.

```
import re
with open('text1.txt', 'r') as rf:
    n = 1
    for line in rf:
        with open('text.txt', 'a') as af:
            border = re.compile(r'\.border')
            border = border.findall(line)
            if border:
                line = line.replace(line, str(border))
                line = line.join(border)
                af.write(line + str(n))
                n += 1
            else:
                af.write(line)
```

Comment: What does "add 1 to regex search" mean?

Comment: you can add an additional variable for a counter, for example `n=1` before the `for` loop, add the `n` in `af.write(line + str(n))`. Then add `n += 1` at the bottom of your program just before quit from `for` loop.

Comment: The code you posted produces an IndentationError Exception - does your post reflect your actual code?